# Difference in sound between a string and a pipe

Tags: physics, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory, mathematical-physics

I am told that I can model the vibration of a guitar string of length $l >0$ by the following Sturm-Liouville equation
$$ -u'' = \lambda u \: \: \text{ on } [0,l],$$
with boundary conditions
$$u(0)=0 \: \text{ and } \: u(l)=0.$$

And the vibrations of air in a pipe (with one end closed and the other open) by
$$-u'' = \lambda u $$
with BCS
$$ u(0)=0 \: \text{ and } u'(l)=0. $$

It is easy to see that the eigenvalues of the first and second problem are $\lambda_k = \left( \frac{k \pi} {l}\right)^2$ and $\lambda_k = \left( \frac{(2k-1) \pi} {2l}\right)^2$, respectively.

My question is how does this explain the difference in sound from a plucked guitar string and a pipe even when they are tunes to the same pitch?

Sorry, maybe this is obvious but I don't have the physical intuition and I am curious...

Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each eigenfunction behaves independently as a simple harmonic oscillator. From the eigenvalues, you can determine the frequencies of oscillation, which are $f_k^s = k/2l$ and $f_k^p = (2k-1)/4l$ for the string and the pipe respectively. These are the frequencies of the *harmonics* that sound when the instruments are played. As you can see, the harmonics of the string are all the multiples of a fundamental frequency $f_1^s$, while those of the pipe are only the *odd* multiples of $f_1^p$. So even if both instruments are tuned to the same pitch, that is, the same fundamental frequency $f_1^s = f_1^p$, the sound of the pipe will be missing the even-numbered harmonics.

Comment: Although surely the precise distribution of the overtones is of significant consequence in _timbre_, the pipe-versus-string comparison, creating the odd-versus-all overtones, has a huge impact apart from the further niceties about precise harmonics. If one has any sort of electronic tone-generation device, the hearable impact of excluding even overtones is immediate and huge! Note that this issue is clear even with the one-dimensional model.